# Unable to copy hidden files using gcloud scp in cloud build - remote builder

Tags: gcloud, scp, google-cloud-build

I'm running cloud build using [remote builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder), able to copy all file in the workspace to my own VM but, unable to copy hidden files

**Command used to copy files**

```
gcloud compute scp --compress --recurse '/workspace/*' [username]@[instance_name]:/home/myfolder --ssh-key-file=my-key --zone=us-central1-a
```

so, this copies only non-hidden files.

**Also used dot operator to copy hidden files**

```
gcloud compute scp --compress --recurse '/workspace/.' [username]@[instance_name]:/home/myfolder --ssh-key-file=my-key --zone=us-central1-a
```

Still not able to copy and got below error

```
scp: error: unexpected filename: .
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to copy hidden files to VM using gcloud scp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: even I tried ```gcloud compute scp --compress --recurse '/workspace/.*' [username]@[instance_name]:/home/myfolder --ssh-key-file=my-key --zone=us-central1-a```  not working

Comment: In cloud build it show like this                                                                                              ```gcloud compute scp --compress --recurse /workspace/. /workspace/.. /workspace/.file1 /workspace/.file2 /workspace/.file3 /workspace/.file4  [username]@[instances]:/home/[username]/  --ssh-key-file=[key] --zone=[zone]
scp: error: unexpected filename: .```

Comment: Its try to copy /workspace/. and /workspace/.. and giving error. I dont want copy those so, how to copy only .***** files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the trailing character after the slash, it may work. For example, this worked for me:

```
gcloud compute scp --compress --recurse 'test/' [username]@[instance_name]:/home/myfolder
```